# Type error function unsubscriptable

Tags: python, function, variables

I get this type of error and I don't know what causes it.

I have this code:

```
def S(x,T,Y,ñ):
    u = 3
    return u

T = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
Y = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
x = 0.5
z = 0
for ñ in range(len(T)-1):
    if T[ñ]<=x and x<T[ñ+1]:
        print("correct: " + str(ñ))
        print(S[x,T,Y,ñ])
```

But then it says:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-98eb96968499> in <module>()
     10     if T[ñ]<=x and x<T[ñ+1]:
     11         print("correct: " + str(ñ))
---> 12         print(S[x,T,Y,ñ])

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
print(S(x,T,Y,ñ))  # round parens instead of the square brackets
```

to call the function.